# Trying to change background gradient in css for flask application

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, flask

I created a flask application using a template that I found online. I am not well-versed with html or css. After calling the application, I realized that the background of the web page has a red-to-blue gradient that I would like to change to a regular dark blue color. Could you please let me know where in my code I can do this. The code is pasted below. Thanks in advance.

I tried changing background-image to none and background to #e6e6e6 (which represents the blue that I want) in multiple places, but it still did not work

```
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans);
.btn { display: inline-block; *display: inline; *zoom: 1; padding: 4px 10px 4px; margin-bottom: 0; font-size: 13px; line-height: 18px; color: #333333; text-align: center;text-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.75); vertical-align: middle; background-color: #00008B; }
.btn-large { padding: 9px 14px; font-size: 15px; line-height: normal; -webkit-border-radius: 5px; -moz-border-radius: 5px; border-radius: 5px; }
.btn:hover { color: #333333; text-decoration: none; background-color: #e6e6e6; background-position: 0 -15px; -webkit-transition: background-position 0.1s linear; -moz-transition: background-position 0.1s linear; -ms-transition: background-position 0.1s linear; -o-transition: background-position 0.1s linear; transition: background-position 0.1s linear; }
.btn-primary, .btn-primary:hover { text-shadow: 0 -1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25); color: #ffffff; }
.btn-primary.active { color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.75); }
.btn-primary:hover, .btn-primary:active, .btn-primary.active, .btn-primary.disabled, .btn-primary[disabled] { filter: none; background-color: #4a77d4; }
.btn-block { width: 100%; display:block; }

* { -webkit-box-sizing:border-box; -moz-box-sizing:border-box; -ms-box-sizing:border-box; -o-box-sizing:border-box; box-sizing:border-box; }

html { width: 100%; height:100%; overflow:scroll; }

body { 
    width: 100%;
    height:100%;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    background-image: none;
    background-color: #e6e6e6;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 18px;
    text-align:center;
    letter-spacing:1.2px;

}
.login { 
    position: absolute;
    top: 40%;
    left: 50%;
    margin: -150px 0 0 -150px;
    width:400px;
    height:450px;
}

.login h1 { color: #fff; text-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.3); letter-spacing:1px; text-align:center; }

input { 
    width: 100%; 
    margin-bottom: 15px; 
    background-image:none;
    background: #e6e6e6;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    padding: 10px;
    font-size: 13px;
    color: #fff;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
    border: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
    border-radius: 4px;
    box-shadow: inset 0 -5px 45px rgba(100,100,100,0.2), 0 1px 1px rgba(255,255,255,0.2);
}
input:focus { box-shadow: inset 0 -5px 45px rgba(100,100,100,0.4), 0 1px 1px rgba(255,255,255,0.2); }
```

Comment: You could consider trying to debug it in the CSS editor view of your browser. E.g. in Firefox you can press F12 key to go to the developer tools and there you can see all the styles on all the elements served by your browser

Comment: @GrosLalo I checked the CSS style elements on the editor view, and for some reason it did not make the same changes that I made on the css file. For example, it did not apply 
background-image: none
background-color: #e6e6e6
do you know what I could do to make sure these changes apply? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try adding !important to override the background from the template. it would look something like this

```
background-image:none !important;
background-color: #e6e6e6 !important;
```

Comment: I added !important, as you outlined, to the body, but it did not change the gradient background.

Comment: if that didn't work you should try background: none #color